# Assigning entity id from code, not by database, two request at the same time

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, asp.net-core

Hey I want to put into database some objects which represents tree structure type:

Each TreeNode element, must have unique id.

My TreeNode

```
public class TreeNode
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

Data which I recived from the front-side of the app

```
  {
    "name": "Tree Node 1",
    "children": 
    [{
        "name": "Tree Node 2",
        "children": 
        [{
            "name": "Tree Node 3",
            "children": 
            [{
                "name": "Tree Node 4",
                "children": 
                [{
                    "name": "Tree Node 5",
                    "children": 
                    [{
                        "name": "Tree Node 6",
                        "children": [],
                        "data": 
                        {
                        }
                    }]
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "Tree Node embeded parent 4",
                    "children": [],
                    "data": 
                    {

                    }
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

My problem is - how can I assign correct Id for each node?

My current solution is, that I'm getting from the database the last Id inserted, and I'm using it to assign to the concreate TreeObject. It works but I thing it not enough good.

This solution has at least one big disadventage - what if two users try to push data into the database at the same time?

Assume that User A, clicked "Save" button.
TreeProcessor recived from database, information that the 100 is last inserted Id.
After TreeProcessor ended with processing data (e.g assigning ids),
data is ready to send to database, but suddenly network connection is slow down ...

At the same time, User B clicked "Save" too but with another data.
Because data from User A, database was not reached yet, database sent 100 as last inserted id .....

Comment: Use  Guid for the key, `public Guid Id { get; set; }`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use an identity column in your database table, and let the database handle assigning the ids? Create a procedure that inserts and returns the identity used, work your way down the tree.

Alternatively wrap the operation up in a transaction, so that the User B can't get an id until User A has written his data. Google TransactionScope for how to do this in C#, or if possible do it within the database (can't quite discern your overall architecture from the question).